# Insert system variables to SBATCH

Tags: slurm, sbatch

I would like to ask you if is possible to pass global system variables to #SBATCH tags.

I would like to do somethink like that

SBATCH FILE

```
#!/bin/bash -l
ARG=64.dat
NODES=4
TASK_PER_NODE=8
NP=$((NODES*TASK_PER_NODE))

#SBATCH -J 'MPI'+'_'+$NODES+'_'+$TASK_PER_NODE
#SBATCH -N $NODES
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=$TASK_PER_NODE
```

It isn't workink so that is why I ask you.

Answer (score 7):

Remember that `SBATCH` parameter lines are viewed by Bash as **comments**, so it will not try to interpret them at all.

Furthermore, the `#SBATCH` directives must be **before any other Bash command** for Slurm to handle them.

Alternatives include setting the parameters in the command line:

```
NODES=4 sbatch --nodes=$NODES ... submitscript.sh
```

or passing the submission script through `stdin`:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
ARG=64.dat
NODES=4
TASK_PER_NODE=8
NP=$((NODES*TASK_PER_NODE))

sbatch <<EOT
#SBATCH -J "MPI_$NODES_$TASK_PER_NODE"
#SBATCH -N $NODES
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=$TASK_PER_NODE

srun ...

EOT
```

In this later case, you will need to run the submission script rather than handing it to `sbatch` since it will run  `sbatch` itself. Note also that string concatenation in Bash is not achieved with the `+` sign.